# $bd\left(A\cup \:B\right)\:\subseteq \left(bd\left(A\right)\right)\cup \left(bd\left(B\right)\right)$

Tags: general-topology

How do I prove this?
$$bd\left(A\cup \:B\right)\:\subseteq \left(bd\left(A\right)\right)\cup \left(bd\left(B\right)\right)$$ where $$A,B\:\subseteq R^n$$
I know that $$bd\:A\:=\:\left(cl\:A\right)\:∩\:cl\left(R^n \ -A\right)$$ but I am not sure if this helps me.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Suppose that $x\in bd(A\cup B)$. Then every open set containing $x$ also contains a point in $A\cup B$ and a point that is in $\mathbb R^n\setminus (A\cup B)$. So every open set containing $x$ contains either a point in $A$ or a point in $B$, as well as a point in neither....

Where can you go with this?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: You presumably know that for any sets $X$ and $Y$ we have

$$\operatorname{cl}(X\cup Y)=(\operatorname{cl}X)\cup\operatorname{cl}Y$$

and

$$\operatorname{cl}(X\cap Y)\subseteq(\operatorname{cl}X)\cap\operatorname{cl}Y\;.$$

Apply the first to $A\cup B$ and the other to $R^n\setminus(A\cup B)$ (after using one of the De Morgan laws) to calculate

$$\operatorname{cl}(A\cup B)\cap\operatorname{cl}\big(\Bbb R^n\setminus(A\cup B)\big)\;;$$

then do a little set algebra to get the desired inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

If $x\in\partial\left(A\cup B\right)$ then there are sequences $\left(u_{n}\right)$
and $\left(v_{n}\right)$ both converging to $x$ and with $u_{n}\notin A\cup B$
and $v_{n}\in A\cup B$ for each $n$.

The sequence $\left(v_{n}\right)$ has a subsequence in $A$ or has
a subsequence in $B$.

Let it be that it has a subsequence $\left(v_{n_{k}}\right)$ in $A$.

There is also sequence $\left(u_{n_{k}}\right)$ in $A^{c}$ and both
sequences converge to $x$.

This allows the conclusion that $x\in\partial A\subseteq\partial A\cup\partial B$.

Likewise we find $x\in\partial B\subseteq\partial A\cup\partial B$
if sequence $\left(v_{n}\right)$ has a subsequence in $B$.